# is there a way to distribute apple apps via ota without the 100 limit?

Tags: ios, iphone, ota

as the title: is there a way to distribute apple apps via ota without the 100 limit?

I noticed that some developer (ie: [gba4ios](http://www.gba4iosapp.com/download/)) allows the download of their app without the 100 limit.

I wonder if I can do the same thing.

Thanks in advance! Fred.

Comment: Enterprise Program and Distribution: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/, $299 / year. and it has to be renewed in every year.

Comment: sorry but with this program I can distribuite the app only to my employees!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called Enterprise Distribution. You have to join Apple's [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/).

> Distribute In-house Apps
>   Distribute proprietary, in-house iOS apps to your employees. You can also securely host and >wirelessly distribute or update in-house apps to employees, keeping them current anywhere, anytime.

Comment: sorry but with this program I can distribuite the app only to my employees!

Comment: GBA4iOS uses exactly that distribution method. That's also the reason why the enterprise distribution certificate they use is always revoked pretty quickly. If you read the conditions closely you will find out that it's in fact possible to distribute outside of your own company, but only under severe restrictions.